# clingo: placing element according to the rules

Tags: clingo

Hello i'm trying to learn more about clingo, have this terms: v(1,2).v(2,1).v(3,4).v(4,3), means that first element cannot be in the same row of the second element, the second cannot be in the same of the first, ecc.. would like to write some rules to find a matrix 2x2 in which element (I,J,N) are placed according to that limits. thanks in advance

```
v(1,2).v(2,1).v(3,4).v(4,3)
rows(1..2).
col(1..2).
1{m(I,J,N) : v(N)}1 :- rows(I), col(J).  
1{m(I,J,N) : rows(I), col(J)}1 :- v(N).
...code...
output 
[1,1,1][1,2,4][2,1,2][2,2,3]
[1,1,4][1,2,1][2,1,2][2,2,3]
[1,1,1][1,2,4][2,1,3][2,2,2]
[1,1,4][1,2,1][2,1,3][2,2,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rule

`1{m(I,J,N) : v(N)}1 :- rows(I), col(J).`

puts into each location of the matrix one v(N) but you do not have v(N) defined, you have v(N,M) defined.

The second rule

```
1{m(I,J,N) : rows(I), col(J)}1 :- v(N).
```

Puts each v(N) in exactly one row and column.

I suggest you replace v(X) by w(X) and define

```
w(N) :- v(N,_).
w(N) :- v(_,N).
```

That means you get all possible values form the v(X,Y) into w.

Comment: ok, now i've obtained all possible solutions (24), how can i find just the four solutions in the question?

Comment: You need to add a constraint that limits the solutions. For example you can ensure that the same number cannot occur in the same column twice with the constraint `:- m(Row1,Col,N), m(Row2,Col,N), Row1 < Row2.`.

Comment: how this constraint works? how it's connected with thw solution in the question? i'm trying to understand better how lp works

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice articles about Answer Set Programming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming and I can also recommend reading the ASP Primer for the basics: http://www.kr.tuwien.ac.at/staff/tkren/pub/2009/rw2009-asp.pdf